# Behaviour of eval() function in Python with formatted paragraphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, eval

I was working with a dataset and came across the following use of `eval()` function to separate out ratings from the description.

Original text:

[image]

After using the eval function:

[image]

The function was automatically able to separate out the ratings from the text associated with the rating. How is this possible and what exactly is the behaviour of the `eval()` function here?

Comment: What do you mean by "separate out the ratings from the text associated with the rating"?

Comment: Your string is a valid Python expression - `eval` evaluates the string it is given as an expression. See the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval

Comment: @kay3 the output suggests that I can use s[0] to extract the "Rated X.X" part and the s[1] to extract the description of the review